# Countdown timer in C without freezing user input

Tags: c

I'm a newbie in C. I'm on the verge of finishing a program. Can anybody teach me how to make a countdown timer while being able to input something? I'm currently using sleep(), and as I've heard, it's bad for threading, and freezes input. Is that right?

Here's the function:

```
void nowPlaying(SONG * h, SONG * t, int * randPrev, int shuffleCon)
{
    SONG * ptr;
    ptr = h->next;
    int random, randCount, mincount = 0, choice = 4, tot = 0, tot2 = 0;

    if(h->next == t) {
        printf("No songs to be played. Add some!\n");
    }
    else if(h->next != t) {
        while(ptr->next != t) {
            tot2 = tot = ((ptr->cdown.minutes*60) + ptr->cdown.secs);
            do {
                printf("------------------------YouTunes------------------------\n");
                printf("========================================================\n");
                printf("TITLE : %s                                            \n", ptr->title);
                printf("ARTIST: %s                                            \n", ptr->artist);
                printf("ALBUM : %s                                            \n", ptr->album);
                switch(ptr->genre) {
                case 1:
                    printf("GENRE : POP                                           \n");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    printf("GENRE : OPM                                           \n");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    printf("GENRE : ROCK                                          \n");
                    break;
                case 4:
                    printf("GENRE : R&B                                           \n");
                    break;
                case 5:
                    printf("GENRE : ACOUSTIC                                      \n");
                    break;
                case 6:
                    printf("GENRE : CLASSICAL                                     \n");
                    break;
                }

                while(tot2 >= 60) {
                    tot2 = tot2 - 60;
                    mincount++;
                    //if(time_left % 60 == 0) mincount++;
                }

                printf("TIME: ");

                if(mincount < 10)
                    printf("0%d", mincount);
                else
                    printf("%d", mincount);

                printf(":");

                if(tot2 < 10)
                    printf("0%d", tot2);
                else if(tot2 == 60)
                    printf("00");
                else
                    printf("%d", tot2);

                printf("\n========================================================\n");
                printf("[1] Prev                 [0]Exit                  [2] Next\n");
                printf("Choice: ");
                //scanf("%d", &choice);
                //timeout(500);
                tot--;
                tot2 = tot;
                mincount = 0;
                sleep(1);
                system("clear");

                if(shuffleCon == 0) {
                    if(choice == 1) {
                        if(ptr->prev == h) {
                            //do nothing
                        }
                        else if(ptr->prev != h) {
                            ptr = ptr->prev;
                        }
                    }
                    else if(choice == 2) {
                        if(ptr->next == t) {
                            //do nothing
                        }
                        else if(ptr->next != t) {
                            ptr = ptr->next;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if(shuffleCon == 1) {
                    if(choice == 1) {
                        random = shuffle(h, t, randPrev);
                        randCount = 0;
                        ptr = h->next;
                        while(randCount != random) {
                            ptr = ptr->next;
                            randCount++;
                        }
                    }
                    else if(choice == 2) {
                        random = shuffle(h, t, randPrev);
                        randCount = 0;
                        ptr = h->next;
                        while(randCount != random) {
                            ptr = ptr->next;
                            randCount++;
                        }

                        if(ptr == t) {
                            ptr = ptr->prev;
                            ptr = ptr->prev;
                        }
                    }
                }
            } while(tot != -1);

            if(shuffleCon == 0)
                ptr = ptr->next;
            else if(shuffleCon == 1) {
                random = shuffle(h, t, randPrev);
                randCount = 0;
                ptr = h->next;
                while(randCount != random) {
                    ptr = ptr->next;
                    randCount++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Consult Professor Google!

Comment: Show your code. Using `sleep`  is often a good thing. But you might have some [event loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) with a multiplexing [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html). Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)

Comment: So says Professor @haccks!

Comment: @devnull; Haven't you heard about him ? :P

Comment: @haccks Yes, I've heard lots about him.  Haven't had a chance to meet yet, though `:)`

Comment: A lot of your code does `if(condition) { ... } else if(!condition) { ... }`.  Testing the inverse of the condition is redundant, since the only way to get to the `else` is when the `condition` in the `if` is false.

Comment: The `while(tot2 >= 60)` loop is a long-winded way of doing a divmod by 60.  You can just do `mincount = tot2 / 60; tot2 = tot2 % 60;`.  Also, `mincount` and `tot2` aren't the most descriptive names; how about `minutes` and `seconds`?

Comment: You can let `printf` deal with zero padding instead of explicitly testing `mincount` and `tot2` for less than zero.  Also, in the `tot2` print, `tot2` can never be equal to `60` thanks to the bound on the `while` loop above (or the `mod` by `60`).  You can just do `printf("%02d:%02d", mincount, tot2);`.

Comment: If `shuffleCon` is really a boolean, you should just say `if(shuffleCon) { ... } else { ... }` instead of explicit testing against `0` and `1` (especially since any non-zero value can be true).

Answer (score 4):

Broadly speaking, one of these:

1. Use `SIGALRM` (see the `alarm` man page), and rely on the signal to interrupt the system call expecting user input.
2. (Better, and certainly a more valuable programming exercise), write an event loop with `select` or `poll` and set the timeout to be the time remaining until the timeout.

For the sort of application you are talking about, (2) would be a better choice.

Comment: Thank you! Will be trying (2).

Comment: Hewre's a good example: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_system_calls/_newselect.htm